# Regex validation for mixed digits for a max of 6 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex validation for mixed length, a total length of 6 characters in that 4-6 characters in caps/numbers and 0-2 spaces.

I tried like

```
^[A-Z0-9]{4,6}+[\s]{0,2}$
```

but it results in a max length of 8 characters, but I need a max of 6 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the alphanumeric chars should only appear at the start of the string and the whitespaces can appear at the end (i.e. the order of the alphanumerics and whitespaces matters), you may use

```
/^(?=.{6}$)[A-Z0-9]{4,6}\s*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V0flJQ/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{6}$)` - the string length is restricted to exactly 6 non-line break chars
- `[A-Z0-9]{4,6}` - 4, 5 or 6 uppercase ASCII letters or digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces  (but actually, only 0, 1 or 2 will be possible to add as the total length is already validated with the lookahead)
- `$` - end of string.

If you want to match the alphanumeric and whitespaces anywhere inside the string, you need a [lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) based regex like

```
^(?=(?:[^A-Z0-9]*[A-Z0-9]){4,6}[^A-Z0-9]*$)(?=(?:\S*\s){0,2}\S*$)[A-Z0-9\s]{6}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xsH7n1/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:[^A-Z0-9]*[A-Z0-9]){4,6}[^A-Z0-9]*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires the presence of 4 to 6 letters or digits anywhere inside the string
- `(?=(?:\S*\s){0,2}\S*$)` - a positive lookahead that requires the presence of 0 to 2 whitespaces anywhere inside the string
- `[A-Z0-9\s]{6}` - 6 ASCII uppercase letters, digits or whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

To shorten the pattern, the second lookahead can be written as `(?!(?:\S*\s){3})`, it will fail the match if there are 3 whitespace chars anywhere inside the string. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xsH7n1/3).

Comment: Wow, that's a beefy regex. You seem quite good at regex.  
Please tell why ```^[\s{0,2}A-Z0-9]{4,6}$``` does not work.

Comment: @itch96 `^[\s{0,2}A-Z0-9]{4,6}$` matches a string that has 4, 5 or 6 chars that are either a whitespace, `{`, digit, `,`, `}`, or uppercase ASCII letters. It is a `^[...]+$` like pattern where `[...]` is a *character class* that matches a *single* char out of the sepcified ones.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thank you for your answer, it worked for 6 character with spaces. is there any way to validate spaces only in the end?

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen What doyou mean by "validate spaces at the end"? Please provide some examples in this [fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/xsH7n1/4).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Hi https://regex101.com/r/fWGjVs/1 this expression worked for me.

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen So, that means you do not want to allow the letters/digits and whitespace *anywhere* inside the string.

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen I will add another solution in two minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can use `|` characters to accommodate several cases into one.

```js
const regex = /(^[A-Z0-9]{4}\s{2}$)|(^[A-Z0-9]{5}\s$)|(^[A-Z0-9]{6}$)/g;
alert(regex.test(prompt('Enter input, including space(s)')));
```

Comment: , Thank you for your answer, it worked for 6 character with spaces. is there any way to validate spaces only in the end?

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen yes, that's what my answer is, it validates 0-2 spaces in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match zero, one or two spaces at the end, you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for those 3 cases.

`^(?:[A-Z0-9]{4}[ ]{2}|[A-Z0-9]{5}[ ]|[A-Z0-9]{6})$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fWGjVs/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[A-Z0-9]{4}[ ]{2}` Match uppercase or digit 4 times followed by 2 spaces
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z0-9]{5}` Match uppercase or digit 5 times followed by 1 space
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z0-9]{6}` Match uppercase or digit 6 times
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` Assert the end of the string

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer, but it is not working for me it allows even 4 characters. for me 6 character is must. and it can contain max of 2 spaces in the end.

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen Do you mean like this with a repetition of `{6}` like [this example](https://regex101.com/r/foNo3v/1) Or do you only want to validate the whitespace at the end like [this example](https://regex101.com/r/fWGjVs/1)

Comment: Hi , https://regex101.com/r/fWGjVs/1 this regex worked for me. thank you.